# Vier Verben in einem Nebensatz (Passiv in Vergangenheit mit Modalverb)

Tags: subordinate-clause, verbal-complex

Ich war bei der Bildung eines Satzes nicht so sicher und deswegen frage ich, ob mein Satz richtig ist:

> Die Patientin hatte vermutlich unbewusste Aggression gegen die Mutter, die auf die Therapeutin **übertragen worden sein könnte**.

Ich frage mich, ob die Positionen der fett markierten Verben richtig sind. Weil ich gesehen habe, dass das grammatische Hauptverb¹ nicht am Ende des Nebensatzes steht, sondern vor den anderen Verben, z. B.:

> Ich weiß, dass er mich hat kommen hören.

In diesem Fall steht *haben* nicht am Ende des Nebensatzes.

Noch dazu eine relevante, allgemeinere Frage: Ich weiß, dass das Hilfsverb *haben* für die Bildung des Perfekts im Nebensatz vor den anderen Verben steht, z. B.:

> Ich weiß, dass er etwas hat sagen müssen.
>
> Es ist klar, dass der Mitarbeiter hätte noch freundlicher sein müssen.

Gilt diese Regel nur für das Hilfsverb *haben* und nicht für Modalverben?

---

¹ Ich weiß nicht, wie ich das Verb eigentlich nennen soll. Ich meine damit z. B. *können* in: »Das kann schon gemacht worden sein.«

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja, die Reihenfolge der Verben in deinem Satz ist richtig.

Die von dir gefundene Regel, dass das finite Verb die Reihung der Verben am Ende anführt, gilt **nur** für das Hilfsverb *haben*, wenn dieses mit dem Ersatzinfinitiv steht. Also vor allem für das Perfekt modaler Ausdrücke.

> …, dass er hat kommen wollen. (Perfekt mit Ersatzinfinitiv)

> …, dass er die Sache gewollt hat. (Perfekt mit Partizip II, da kein modaler Ausdruck)

Zum Beispiel mit dem Verb *sehen* sind aber beide Perfekt-Varianten bei identischer Bedeutung möglich:

> …, dass er das Ende kommen gesehen hat.  (Perfekt mit Partizip II)

> …, dass er das Ende hat kommen sehen. (Perfekt mit Ersatzinfinitiv)

Außerdem kann man das Hilfsverb *werden* des Futur I modaler Ausdrücke wahlweise an den Anfang oder das Ende der Reihung stellen:

> …, dass er kommen können wird. (Futur I mit *werden* am Ende)

> …, dass er wird kommen können. (Futur I mit *werden* am Anfang)

Im Futur II führt *haben* keinen Ersatzinfinitiv.

> …, dass er kommen gewollt haben wird. (Futur II mit *werden* am Ende)

> …, dass er wird kommen gewollt haben. (Futur II mit *werden* am Anfang)

> …, dass er das Ende kommen gesehen haben wird. (Futur II mit *werden* am Ende)

> …, dass er das Ende wird kommen gesehen haben. (Futur II mit *werden* am Anfang)

Comment: In der Duden-Grammatik, 9. Auflage, Randnummer 684 heißt es: "Das Hilfsverb *haben* kann, auch wenn es mit dem Ersatzinfinitiv verbunden ist, selbst im Infinitiv stehen". Beispiel: *Er wird leider nicht haben kommen können*. Parallel also: *dass er das Ende wird haben kommen sehen*.

Comment: Ich war mir nicht sicher, ob diese Kombination auch erlaubt ist. Die Kombination *… haben kommen sehen wird.* kommt mir jedenfalls seltsam vor.

Comment: Vielen Dank für deine ausführliche Antwort!